# How to remove a white space at the end of a string in java?

Tags: java, string, trim, spaces, remove-if

I am trying to remove exactly one white space at the end of a string.
eg.
I want "   XXXX " to be "   XXXX".
The trim() method in java removes all leading and trailing whitespaces.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you give an example which actually has more than one leading/trailing whitespace character?

Comment: "     XXXX    " . If I use the trim() method it gives me "XXXX" but I only want "   XXXX  ". I want to remove exactly one whitespace at the end

Comment: Note that "white space" means the category of characters that represent some kind of empty space. If you wish to remove specifically space characters (Unicode U+0020) and nothing else, then use the term "space character".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to trim whitespace at the end, use `String#replaceAll()` with an appropriate regex:

```java
String input = " XXXX ";
String output = input.replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
System.out.println("***" + input + "***");   // *** XXXX ***
System.out.println("***" + output + "***");  // *** XXXX***
```

If you really want to replace just *one* whitespace character at the end, then replace on `\s$` instead of `\s+$`.

Comment: This is so much overkill to remove a single space at the end, just `if (s.charAt(s.length() - 1) == ' ') s = s.substring(0, s.length() - 1);` would be sufficient.

Comment: @Izruo Yes, you could use a substring operation, and FWIW it would probably be faster than my answer.  But if the goal is to remove arbitrary number of whitespaces, then your suggestion becomes less attractive.  You would have to do a regex match first before taking a substring.  `replaceAll` would be easier.

Comment: @Izruo Do you *really* find that more readable/maintainable than using `replaceAll`? *I* don’t.

Answer (score 3):

## `String#stripTrailing()`

Since Java 11, `String` has a built-in method to to this: [`String#stripTrailing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#stripTrailing())

It can be used like

```
String input = " XXX ";
String output = input.stripTrailing();
```

Note that, other than `String.trim()`, this method removes any [whitespace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#isWhitespace(int)) at the end of the string, not just spaces.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

```
public String trim(String str) { 
 int len = str.length(); 
 int st = 0; 

 char[] val = str.toCharArray(); 

 while ((st < len) && (val[len - 1] <= ' ')) { 
  len--; 
 } 
 return str.substring(st, len); 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).